# Trying to index a list of strings and delete a string based on their index

Tags: python, string, pandas, list, indexing

I have a list of lists (called copy), where the elements inside each list (inside the big list) are strings representing certain movies(like shown below):

```
[['history', '1960', 'action'],
 ['1960', 'western', 'adventure'],
 ['3d', 'fantasy'],
 ['agent', 'action', 'adventure'], 
....]
```

Some of these words represent movie genres. What I'm trying to do is, for each list, look for the words that genres (by looking if these words are in a set called set_genres), put them at the beginning of the list and attach the word 'movie' after it. If there are more than one genre in the list, I want to only attach the word 'movie after the last genre. Set_genres and the desired output are below:

```
set_genres={'action',
 'adventure',
 'animation',
 'comedy',
 'crime',
 'documentary',
 'drama',
 'family',
 'fantasy',
 'foreign',
 'history',
 'horror',
 'music',
 'mystery',
 'romance',
 'science_fiction',
 'thriller',
 'tv_movie',
 'war',
 'western'}

#Output
[['history','action movie', '1960'],
 ['western','adventure movie', '1960'],
 ['fantasy movie','3d'],
 ['action', 'adventure movie', 'agent'], 
....]
```

The code I'm using to try and achieve this is the following:

```
keys=[]
for list_top in copy:
        for idx, word in enumerate(list_top):
                if word in set_genres:
                        keys.append((idx,word))
        keys.sort(reverse=True)
        for idx, word in keys:
                del list_top[idx]
        for idx, word in keys:
                if idx==len(keys)-1:
                        list_top.insert(0,'{} movie'.format(word))
                else:
                        list_top.insert(0,word)
```

This, however, is not working and I haven't been able to figure out why. It's giving me the following error:

```
indexes=[]...
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
      8                         keys.sort(reverse=True)
      9                 for idx, word in keys:
---> 10                         del list_top[idx]
     11                 for idx, word in keys:
     12                         if idx==len(keys)-1:

IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

If anyone has any idea what could be wrong, I'd appreciate your help!

Comment: please also post a sample of `set_genres` in relevance to the sample inout list provided.

Comment: Don't modify lists that you're iterating over.

Comment: @anky_91 I added that above!

Comment: @DanielRoseman could you please tell me why? But also, copy is already a deepcopy of the original list

Comment: @J.Doe, the 2nd item in desired output is unsorted `['western','action movie', '1960']` - is that intended? does the order of genres matter?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest that was a mistake on my end. Already changed it above!

Comment: @J.Doe, you did not get it, I was mentioned about alphabetic order of genres

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest oh sorry!! I didn't really think about that. Being in alphabetic order is not really relevant for what I want

Comment: what is more than 1 element is present in `set_genres`

Comment: @J.Doe, in such case - the 1st item should be `['history', 'action movie', '1960']` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some modification to what ever @Дмитрий Сиденко has suggested:

```
for ind_copy, list_top in enumerate(copy):
   keys=[]
   for ind_list_top, word  in enumerate(list_top):
      if word in set_genres:
         keys.append(word)
         del list_top[ind_list_top]
   keys[-1] = '{} movie'.format(keys[-1])
   copy[ind_copy] = keys + list_top
```

Comment: With this I also get the IndexError: list index out of range and it's pointing to the 'keys[-1]='{} movie'.format(keys[-1])' line

Comment: Then we need to check whether keys is empty or not before appending movie. could you try this:
 ` 
`if(len(keys)>0):
     keys[-1] = '{} movie'.format(keys[-1])
     copy[ind_copy] = keys + list_top `

Answer (score 1):

Extended `sorted` approach with optimized *reversed* traversal:

```
genres_set = {'action', 'adventure', 'animation', 'comedy', 'crime', 'documentary', 'drama', 'family',
              'fantasy', 'foreign', 'history', 'horror', 'music', 'mystery', 'romance', 'science_fiction',
              'thriller', 'tv_movie', 'war', 'western'}
inp_list = [['history', '1960', 'action'],
            ['1960', 'western', 'adventure'],
            ['3d', 'fantasy'],
            ['agent', 'action', 'adventure']
            ]
genres_res = [sorted(lst, key=lambda x: x in genres_set, reverse=True) for lst in inp_list]
for lst in genres_res:
    for i, genre in enumerate(lst[::-1]):
        if genre in genres_set:
            lst[-i-1] += ' movie'   # updating the last genre in sublist
            break
print(genres_res)
```

The output:

```
[['history', 'action movie', '1960'], ['western', 'adventure movie', '1960'], ['fantasy movie', '3d'], ['action', 'adventure movie', 'agent']]
```

---

Alternative way could be using *generator* function:

```
def arrange_genres(inp_list):
    for lst in inp_list:
        lst = sorted(lst, key=lambda x: x in genres_set, reverse=True)
        for i, genre in enumerate(lst[::-1]):
            if genre in genres_set:
                lst[-i - 1] += ' movie'
                break
        yield lst

res = list(arrange_genres(inp_list))
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `pandas` is tagged, here is a way using `np` and `pd`:

```
df=pd.DataFrame(l)
```

---

```
         0        1          2
0  history     1960     action
1     1960  western  adventure
2       3d  fantasy       None
3    agent   action  adventure
```

---

Conditions:

```
c1=df.ffill(1).iloc[:,-1].isin(set_genres) #check if the last element isin set_genres
c2=df.eq(df.ffill(1).iloc[:,-1],axis=0) #check where it matches the df elements
c3=df.isna() #check for None
```

---

Choices:

```
choice1=df.mask(c2,df.astype(str)+' movie') #mask c1 and add movie to the elements
choice2=''
```

---

Then `np.sort` and `np.select`

```
pd.DataFrame(np.sort(np.select([c1[:,None]&c2,c3],[choice1,choice2],default=df)).T[::-1].T)
```

---

```
               0                1       2
0        history     action movie    1960
1        western  adventure movie    1960
2  fantasy movie               3d        
3          agent  adventure movie  action
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
set_genres={'action',
 'adventure',
 'animation',
 'comedy',
 'crime',
 'documentary',
 'drama',
 'family',
 'fantasy',
 'foreign',
 'history',
 'horror',
 'music',
 'mystery',
 'romance',
 'science_fiction',
 'thriller',
 'tv_movie',
 'war',
 'western'}

base = [['history', '1960', 'action'],
 ['1960', 'western', 'adventure'],
 ['3d', 'fantasy'],
 ['agent', 'action', 'adventure']]

print(set_genres)
print(base)

for movie in base:
    for s in movie:
        if s not in set_genres:
            movie.remove(s)
            movie.append(s)


print(base)
```

Outputs:

```
[['history', 'action', '1960'], ['western', 'adventure', '1960'], ['fantasy', '3d'], ['action', 'adventure', 'agent']]
```

Comment: Thanks! This does add the word 'movie', but  when there's 2 genres, it adds the word 'movie' to both of them, not just to the last one. Also, it doesn't put the genre at the beginning of the list like I wanted

Comment: Can you provide sample input list with word 'movie', to be more specific ? I will update my code then.

Answer (score 0):

About your error:

You're modifying the list you're iterating over. If you do that, the size of the list shrinks, so eventually this will point beyond the list's boundaries.

This is what you need:

```py
copy = [['history', '1960', 'action'],
 ['1960', 'western', 'adventure'],
 ['3d', 'fantasy'],
 ['agent', 'action', 'adventure']]

set_genres={'action',
 'adventure',
 'animation',
 'comedy',
 'crime',
 'documentary',
 'drama',
 'family',
 'fantasy',
 'foreign',
 'history',
 'horror',
 'music',
 'mystery',
 'romance',
 'science_fiction',
 'thriller',
 'tv_movie',
 'war',
 'western'}

for ind_copy, list_top in enumerate(copy):
  word_finded = False
  print(list(reversed(list_top)))
  for ind_list_top, word  in enumerate(list(reversed(list_top))):
      if not word_finded:
        if word in set_genres:
          list_top[len(list_top) - ind_list_top - 1] = '{} movie'.format(word)
          word_finded = True
  if word_finded:
    copy[ind_copy] = list_top

print(copy)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help! This does add the word 'movie'. However, when there's 2 genres, it adds the word 'movie' to both of them, not just to the last one. Also, it doesn't put the genre at the beginning of the list like I wanted

Comment: @J.Doe Do you want to change the word that will be alphbetic first?

Comment: For the words that are genres , I want to attach them to the beginning of the list. Then, if there are more than 1 genre, i want to attach the word 'movie' only to the last genre

Comment: @J.Doe Changed as you say

Answer (score 0):

you can use list comprehension

```
for i,list_top in enumerate(copy):
    temp = [x for x in list_top if x in set_genres]
    temp[-1]=temp[-1]+' movie'
    copy[i] = temp + [x for x in list_top if x not in set_genres]

print(copy)

>>output
[['history', 'action movie', '1960'], ['western', 'adventure movie', '1960'], ['fantasy movie', '3d'], ['action', 'adventure movie', 'agent']]
```